# GraphDB: use similarity search with embedded repository

Tags: graphdb

I have been using GraphDB's (version 9.2) similarity search from the workbench. Now I also want to use this feature for an embedded repository using graphdb-free-runtime 9.2.1. However I have no clue how this feature can be used from the APIs provided by the runtime. My questions are:

- In http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/semantic-similarity-searches.html it is mentioned that similarity search is a plugin. However I could not find any such plugin within the runtime. Do I have to load it from some external resource? Where?
- Is there any documentation or example how to create a similarity index programmatically?
- Would it be an option to run the workbench as some kind of server and access the similarity search via REST API? However the REST API documentation at http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/9.0/free/using-the-workbench-rest-api.html does not mention any API for similarity searches. Am I missing something?

Any hints or pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add similarity plugin runtime, setting following "graphdb.extra.plugins" property to directory where similarity-plugin (you could find such into GDB instance -> dist/lib/plugins) is located , or:

1. -Dgraphdb.extra.plugins=directory
2. System.setProperty("graphdb.extra.plugins", "directory");

You may create index programmatically using SPARQL or:

to create similarity text index "allNews" execute following update:

```
PREFIX : <http://www.ontotext.com/graphdb/similarity/>
PREFIX inst: <http://www.ontotext.com/graphdb/similarity/instance/>
PREFIX pred: <http://www.ontotext.com/graphdb/similarity/psi/>
insert {
    inst:allNews :createIndex "-termweight idf" ;
        :analyzer "org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.EnglishAnalyzer" ;
        :documentID ?documentID .
        ?documentID :documentText ?documentText .
} where {
    SELECT ?documentID ?documentText {
        ?documentID ?p ?documentText .
        filter(isLiteral(?documentText))
    }
}
```

to delete index "allNews" execute following update:

```
PREFIX :<http://www.ontotext.com/graphdb/similarity/>
PREFIX inst:<http://www.ontotext.com/graphdb/similarity/instance/>

insert { inst:allNews :deleteIndex '' } where {}
```

to rebuild index "allNews":

```
PREFIX :<http://www.ontotext.com/graphdb/similarity/>
PREFIX inst:<http://www.ontotext.com/graphdb/similarity/instance/>

insert { inst:allNews :rebuildIndex '' } where {}
```

followed by the create query!

to list all created indexes, execute following query:

```
PREFIX :<http://www.ontotext.com/graphdb/similarity/>
PREFIX inst:<http://www.ontotext.com/graphdb/similarity/instance/>

select ?index ?status ?type
where {
  ?index :status ?status .
  ?index :type ?type .
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot! Both with finding and embedding the plugin as well as formulating the proper queries to use the plugin.